# cmake project - rsync copies more then it should

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, rsync, visual-studio-2022

My cmake project is in a sub directory as a part of a much larger repo like so:

```
repo_dir
  |
  some java projects dirs...
  |
  some dotnet projects dirs..
  |
  my cmake project dir
     CMakeLists.txt
```

I use VS 2022 and build my project on a remote linux machine.
when i try to sync and build my project it copies the entire "repo_dir" to the remote machine and not just "my cmake project dir", why is that? what to i need to set in order to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You can (and, I think, should) use [CMake presets](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html) for that and other project management things which involve remote development with MSVS. Check the MS [Configure and build with CMake Presets in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/cmake-presets-vs?view=msvc-170) to learn how to do it and use `copySourcesOptions` from the [vendor map](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/cmake-presets-json-reference?view=msvc-170) to customize what to copy.

Comment: Hi, Thanks i will take a look at copySourceOptions, btw, i do use the CMake.presets.json to define my remote build machine and preset stuff like gcc/g++ location etc. but:
a. I don't understand logic behind why would CMake jump one directory up and copy the entire repo (what defines that?) i mean with that logic why not copy the entire disk?
b. this source dir definition feels to me like more a project definition and not build depended since i want my root dir to be well defined on all build configuration

Comment: @RoeyNissim that's not about CMake it is MSVS. CMake knows nothing about remote builds and other stuff MSVS provides so I can't answer this question, it is better to ask guys from MS directly. Where do you have a .vs directory?

Comment: This I understand (that's why i mentioned i use VS2022), but you are correct when i wrote "why would CMake jump one directory up..." i meant 
why would VS instruct rsync to jump one dir up?
and seems (as you mentioned) that what's responsible for that is the location of the .vs dir (which for some reason is in the repo_dir) - so i guess that is why VS behaves like that.
now all that left is to understand how to change that and define a diffrent source root dir - i looked at copySourceOptions but could not find anything relevant any other places i should look?

Comment: @RoeyNissim `copySourceOptions` allows you to exclude folders you don't want to copy. As to the "sourceDir", I don't know. You posted too little info about your repo to make any comment. Where are your CMake-related files (all of them), how do you open your project in VS etc.

Comment: ya i saw the exclusion option but i rather go positive (define root dir) then go negative (exclude all other dirs) since negative needs to managed (update everytime a new dir is added).
other then that, i only have one cmake project directory and the dir structure is like i mentioned above (different java and dotnet projects).

Comment: i open my project by opening VS then added the local repo then VS goes into solution view and shows you all sln and one cmake project i double-clicked the cmake project - maybe i should delete the .vs folder and retry to open the project

Comment: @RoeyNissim open CMake project by Open->CMake..., then choose the top CMake file.

Comment: will do, do you think i should delete the .vs dir?

Comment: @RoeyNissim you can do it. It will create another one if needed anyway. That directory isn't important.